# Oxidising nature of hydrogen peroxide

Tags: oxidation-state

It is said that $\ce {H2O2}$ behaves like a reducing agent in an external oxidizing environment but along with $\ce {H2SO4}$ a strong oxidizing agent it oxidizes $\ce {FeSO4}$ to $\ce {Fe2(SO4)3}$ in acidic medium. How and why?

Comment: Why what? Yes, H2O2 (like a good many other compounds) can act as a reducing agent or as an oxidizing agent, or even as both at once, depending on circumstances. There is nothing special about it.

Comment: Hi maybe you can clarify a little bit your question! You are asking `How hydrogen peroxide can be an oxidizing agent and a reducing agent depending on the pH?` I think it's a good question... We can help you to edit it so it's more clear...

Comment: Also note that $\ce{H2SO4}$ is usually not an oxidizing agent in water chemistry.

Comment: One way you can look at it, at least based on what my teacher said, is that the oxidation state of O in H2O2 is intermediate between 0 and -2. Thus, it shares the reducing ability of oxides as well as the oxidising ability of dioxygen.